# Determine if item is visible on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have built a basic interface consisting of a list of `CardView`’s inside a `RecyclerView`. When a card is added I need to know if it is visible on screen or not.

I am trying to obtain this by using the layout manager’s `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` method, however it seems to return a result one item less than expected. For example if I have 1 card which is visible `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` returns `-1` (where I would expect the index of the visible card would be `0`).

My simplified core methods are as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    items = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView recycList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recycList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recycList.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recycList.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new ChildAttachListener(llm));
    adapter = new RecycAdapter(items);
    recycList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void addItem(){
    items.add(new Item());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ChildAttachListener implements OnChildAttachStateChangeListener{
    LinearLayoutManager llm;

    public ChildAttachListener(LinearLayoutManager llm){
        super();
        this.llm = llm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {

        System.out.println("Items size = "+items.size() + ", Last Visible Item = "+llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

    }
}
```

Return when first item is added:

```
Items size = 1, Last Visible Item = -1
```

Return when second item is added:

```
Items size = 2, Last Visible Item = 0
Items size = 2, Last Visible Item = 0
```

Return when third item is added:

```
Items size = 3, Last Visible Item = 0
Items size = 3, Last Visible Item = 1
Items size = 3, Last Visible Item = 1
```

In all cases all items are visible (I can have 7 visible items on screen).

Could someone please help me understand the return of `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` and suggest how I can determine if a card is visible on screen when adding it?

**EDIT:**
I should clarify that my real objective is to know if an item is visible  when I add it (using my `addItem()` method). If there is a simple way of doing that inside the `addItem()` method even better.

Comment: have you tried with findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()?

Comment: Yes, with identical results for the example above (i.e. adding 3 items, as they are all completely visible).

Comment: a -1 value match with the NO_POSITION constant according to the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition%28%29

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that bit, what I do not understand is why -1 being returned when I have a visible item? i.e. if items.size() = 1 and my OnChildAttachStateChangeListener has triggered (suggesting the item has been attached) and I can see the item on screen, why is findLastVisibleItemPosition() returning -1 and not 0? 

I think it may be related to the following line from the reference docs _"This position does not include adapter changes that were dispatched after the last layout pass."_, however I am not sure when the last layout pass was done and how to trigger one?

Comment: Sadly i know the same as you

Comment: @Ratty : I might be shooting in the dark here, but I do believe that the recycler view returns the number of visible items as 2 more than actually seen; one before the first and one after the last. This is probably due to the fact that the listview is contiguous onscreen and might contain partially visible list items ( I do think that partially visible differs in how we see it and how the system sees it.)

Answer (score 13):

For those interested I have solved the problem by calling findLastVisibleItemPosition inside a Handler:

```
@Override
public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println(llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition());
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: After adding items to the adapter the layout manager did not report correctly if it was called just after it. With this, it worked! Thanks!